# ArrayList not updating with objects received from DataSnapshots

Tags: java, android, arraylist

```
    public class QuestionCatalog extends AppCompatActivity {
        //TextView for displaying the selected subject
        TextView subjectLabel;
        //String to contain the subject selected by the user
        String selectedSubject;
        //Database Reference to questions
        DatabaseReference databaseReference;
        //ArrayList containing all the questions of a given subject
        ArrayList<Question> questions;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_question_catalog);

            //Get the data intent was launched with
             Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    //Determine which category the user wants to view questions for
    selectedSubject = extras.getString("Subject");
    //Initialize questions ArrayList
            questions = new ArrayList<Question>();
//Initialize DatabaseReference
            databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("questions");
            //Populate the array list with questions relevant to the subject
            populateQuestionArrayList();
            //Initialize the text view for displaying the subject
            subjectLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewSubjectLabel);
            //Try to get a Question object from the ArrayList for demo purposes
            questions.get(0);

    }

        private void populateQuestionArrayList() {
            databaseReference.child(selectedSubject).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for (DataSnapshot question : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                            Question q = question.getValue(Question.class);
                            questions.add(q);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

My code crashes from the last line in onCreate with an IndexOutOfBound exception, meaning the Question objects are not being added to the ArrayList. The objects I create function fine in the onDataChange method. Can someone please explain this to me?

Comment: This is because you don't add any question to your questions array list. Maybe, using the debugger inside the populateQUestionArrayList it will help you

Comment: The listener's onDataChnaged method is not called when onCreate is called... If the listener is triggered then only one of the listener's method is executed..

Comment: public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot question : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                        Question q = question.getValue(Question.class);
                        subjectLabel.setText(q.getQuestionDescription());
                        questions.add(q);
                }
            }                                                                                                           Changes the label so I don't believe that onDataChanged method is not called? @Jai Also I am adding questions in onDataChanged, no?

Comment: What I m saying is that I only see `questions.add` in `onDataChanged` which adds to your arraylist and it is not called so the arraylist is empty and you trying to access an empty arraylist

Answer (score 0):

The `onDataChange` method is **asynchronous**. It may take some time (very small though) to trigger. Right after you are listening to the `onDataChange` via the `valueEventListener`, you're trying to access the ArrayList which may not have been populated yet.

So i would suggest you access the `ArrayList` when you're done adding all the elements from the `databaseSnapshot` just after the end of `for` statement inside `onDataChanged`